Why Does Displacement Separate Faces on Sculpted Models?
I am trying to apply a displacement to a sculpted plate, but when I apply this the faces separate and air is left between them.
This problem only occurs on sculpted models. You can see in the video that the one on the left that I didn't apply sculpt to works fine. The one on the right does not work well with displacement.


I'm not sure what you mean by "Brushed" do you mean "sculpted"? And can you upload some images of what your meshes look like from a topology level? Or even better can you share your Blender project file? Instructions for sharing.

Yes, I mean sculpted. I used "Multires" modifier with 6 subdivision. The problem is solved if I activate "Shade Smooth" on it. Applying shade flat: link, applying shade smooth: link

I’m voting to close this question because the description is apparently so imprecise that the answer you yourself posted doesn’t make any sense from the natural interpretation of it.

You should’ve included those images in your question and answer, respectively.

Applying "Shade Smooth" solves the problem.

That doesn’t make any sense.

@TheLabCat But it is true. This problem only exists in EEVEE or in case of the question in the Material Preview because it uses EEVEE. Material-based displacement was not possible before version 4.2, seems like this is not yet working as well as in Cycles. My guess is, while Cycles treats edges on flat shaded meshes as if they were all sharp, EEVEE seems to treat them as split edges. Therefore they are displaced separated from each other. Only when switching to smooth shading, the normals between two faces are averaged out and they are connected through their mutual edge.

@Soma By the way, this means you will not have these problems when you are using Cycles.

@GordonBrinkmann he added screenshots via a comment on his original question that showed this to me, and your explanation makes it make sense.
